# SELECT disc before date - SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I've got a piece of code here, but I'm not sure if it works 100%. So I thought I could ask you, Google didn't gave me a straight answer so I hope you can. What I want to do is to show a DIV if the current date is before the date which has been given in the database. If the date is in the past then my DIV shouldn't be shown.

PHP/SQL:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tournaments` WHERE `deadline` > CURDATE()");
```

Is this the correct code for what I'm looking for?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Probably yes. What is the datatype of `deadline`?

Comment: What is the datatype of column deadline?

Comment: If it is `Date`, it should work fine. It will give you all rows where `deadline` is tomorrow and afterwards (but not today or in the past).

Comment: What do you want to do if the date is today (`deadline = CURDATE()`)?  You didn't define that...

Comment: Yeah, I also noticed that, but I guess I just have to add = to =>, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

might want to add the equal as it would not display div's with today as a deadline

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tournaments` WHERE `deadline` >= CURDATE()");
```

otherwise that seems fine. you would build the logic:

```
<?PHP
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    // nothing to show
    echo "<div>No results</div>\n";
} else {
    // found data to display
    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
        <div style='float:left;width: 150px;'>Data Title</div>\n";
        <div style='float:left; margin-left: 15px;'><?PHP echo $Row['yourdatafield']; ?></div>;
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <?PHP
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If I want to show multiply DIVs with the while() should I just remove the IF with "while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))"?

Comment: nah .. the while will take each row of data and display it .. if you need multiple data fields just add more echo lines with those other data fields still within the while. did that answer your question? i updated the answer to address what i think you're asking.

Comment: My bad... What I meant was adding more rows as you described it in your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

no, you should use DATEDIFF()

```
"SELECT * FROM `tournaments` WHERE DATEDIFF(`deadline`, CURDATE()) > 0"
```

Comment: either would work fine, just a matter of preference. still a valid query both ways.

Comment: No, this will be slower. No index can be used and there is a call to unneeded function (a function that will be called for **every** row of the table).